# Does this iptable rule affect all incoming traffic?

Tags: iptables

### Question

If I use the following conditions on an iptable rule, what is the effect? 
Is it the same as specifying any connection targeted at myself?

```
! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL
```

---

### Background

Specifically, I'm using it to redirect ports on my host (with public IP, say, 150.200.30.40) to one of my LXC containers (with IP 10.0.3.202). It appears to me that these to rules are equivalent for traffic addressed at my host's public IP address.

```
## IPTABLE RULE FOR INCOMING CONNECTIONS??
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.202:22

## EQUIVALENT RULE?? (for connections directed at 150.200.30.40)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 150.200.30.40 -p tcp --dport 2222  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.202:22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are cases when these two are not identical. Here is why (I am not discussing here other matches like protocol and port):

1. First rule matches when packet is destined to a local address (not including 127.0.0.0 range).
2. Second rule matches when packet is destined to a specific IP address (assigned to this machine as you mentioned).

They will identical if there is only one address assigned to this machine which is 150.200.30.40. Both will be matching packet destined to a local address not matching 127.0.0.0 range.

They will be different when there is at least one address assigned to any interface other than mentioned public IP (and of course excluding special private range 127.0.0.0).

If the mentioned public IP is not assigned to this machine, they are different for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Ok, I think that I have grasped the differences you comment. In that case, can I use the first rule for situations where I don't know my public address beforehand, but wish for a similar behaviour? Are there any security concerns?

Comment: @andresgongora: Usually, the protection (security concerns) is handled in filter table not in nat table. You can always deny/allow whatever you want in `INPUT` chain in filter table.

Comment: That's the weird thing: my INPUT policy is to drop all apckets unless otherwise specified, and I've never set TCP port  2222 to accept, yet it get's correctly routed to my private network and port 22. Have I missed something?

Comment: @andresgongora: You said it is routed to private network. This means `INPUT` chain will not be checked for this traffic. You need to look at `FORWARD` chain instead.